# java - calling a method in a subclass

Tags: java

Hey there, I'm trying to call a method in a subclass, savingsaccount. when i call this method, it involves a field called balance in the superclass, called account. When i try to involve this field in the method, it says that the field is private and cannot be accessed. Is there a way around this with keeping the field private? We are not supposed to change the access type.

Kind regards and much appreciation for any help

Comment: Where's the code ? Dude, you must provide us with a "sample" code.

Comment: No. A better answer would require a better question.

Comment: Or let him do his own homework.

Answer (score 2):

No. The superclass should provide appropriate methods to access the field's value appropriately, possibly performing validation.

The whole point of making a field private is to stop other classes from accessing it *directly* - instead they have to go through the methods you expose.

Comment: could you explain with an example in this scenario.

Comment: @Deepak: Without seeing any of the code to either class, or knowing what the purposes of the classes are, it's pretty hard to do so :(

Answer (score 0):

Add a protected getter method in the superclass to return the balance value, such as this:

```
protected double getBalance() {
      return this.balance;
}
```

This method will be visible to subclasses but not visible externally. It allows you also to keep the balance field private.

Answer (score 0):

If it's private you can't get at it, that's it. The author of the superclass has the responsibility to make their class open to extension. If they chose not to allow this kind of extension then there's nothing to be done.

Now check, did they provide accessor methods, or anticipate your need for extension in some other way? If you can talk to the author ask them whether they considered this need.

Answer (score 0):

private means that the variable is private to that class.  protected would mean that subclasses can access it and public means anyone can see it.  If you can't change the access type then you should provide an accessor method in the super-class:

```
public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
```

In the sublclass you can then see the balance by calling `getBalance`

Answer (score 0):

use reflection.

hey, I'm just answering the question as is.

Comment: You mean this? `int balance = ((Integer) getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("balance").get(this)).intValue();` not to mention the following exceptions: `IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException`. Sounds like fun :-)