# java subclass method referring to field in superclass help!

Tags: java

I have a subclass called savingsaccount. I want the method(addInterest) in savingsaccount to refer to a field in the superclass called balance. It says that balance has private access. How do i go around getting rid of this? I'm not allowed to set the field in the superclass to anything else other than private. ANy help is appreciated. This is the method in savingsaccount.

```
public void addInterest()
{
    deposit(balance * interestRate / 100);
}
```

Comment: instead of posting a new Question, edit [your old one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959558/java-calling-a-method-in-a-sublcass)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java - calling a method in a subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959558/java-calling-a-method-in-a-subclass)

Answer (score 5):

Create a getter method, like this:-

```
public abstract class MySuperClass {
    private float balance;

    protected float getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}

public class SavingsAccount extends MySuperClass {
    public void addInterest() {
        deposit(super.getBalance() * interestRate / 100);
    }

    private void deposit(..) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need `super` unless the subclass overrides `getBalance()`

Comment: @Jason: You are correct. I'm using it to illustrate to @robert that the child class is calling the superclass' API, or else he might ask "Why there's no `getBalance()` in `SavingsAccount` class?". :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a getter in the superclass?  If it's private it's not accessible -- period -- so you're going to have to either make it protected, or add a get method:

```
public class YourSuperClass {
    public YourType getSuperClassField() {
        return superClassField;
    }
}
```

(Technically you could use reflection -- but that would be a really bad idea here, IMO)

Comment: getSuperClassField() needs a return type. Depending on what type the 'balance' field is in the super-class, you may run into problems if you're passing back an object ref; If the field is a primitive type, it's safer because you're passing back a value rather than a ref, no?

Comment: Additionally, if you only want to expose the super-class's data to derived classes, then protected scope is probably better, following the general rule of "keep your API as private as possible"?

Answer (score 1):

put

```
protected BalanceType getBalance() { return this.balance; }
```

in the superclass, where `BalanceType` is the type of `balance` (you didn't specify it)

Comment: You have a missing return type. :)

Comment: Heh. Thanks -- the OP didn't specify one.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a getter method if you have source code as everyone said, otherwise you can use reflection to access the private members to access.